# How to do Button Group selected and change color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to design buttons (I'm using bootstrap) in the Blazor project. I have 2 button groups on one Razor page. 3 to 4 buttons in each group. I want to use Javascript to change the color button which is onclick function.

1. User will click any button from group 1 (when clicking change color to green) and click the button from group 2 without deselecting button from group 1.
2. The onclick call need to be here `<div class="btn-group">` because I already have onclick on my button`<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => UpdateTheChart(13)">@Language.T37</button>`

I have tried `:focus` in CSS but only 1 button can be select.
This is my code, I take out the onclick in button for test purposes.

```css
.btn:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  /*green*/
  background-color: #85c995;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="width:30%">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="outline-color:red; ">Sunday</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tuesday</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Friday</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="width:70%">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">9 am</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">2 pm</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">5 pm</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">8 pm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the issue you faced with the onclick event?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I add something like this

`$('.btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});`

Comment: And it wasn't working? It looks fine to me. Append it in the question

Comment: Yes not working. Im not sure why.... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function switch_to_green(el){

  //Check clicked button is on the same group
  if(el.parentElement.getAttribute("data-group") == 1){
  //Get all buttons of group 1
  let g1_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#group1 .btn');
  for(let i =0; i<g1_buttons.length;i++){
    //Remove green color from unselected buttons
    g1_buttons[i].classList.remove('green');
  }
  }else{
  //Get all buttons of group 2
  let g2_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#group2 .btn');
  for(let i =0; i<g2_buttons.length;i++){
    //Remove green color from unselected buttons
    g2_buttons[i].classList.remove('green');
  }
  }
  //Add green color to the only selected one
  el.classList.add('green');

}
```

```css
.btn:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        /*green*/
        background-color: #85c995;
}
.btn.green{
    color: white;
    /*green*/
    background-color: #85c995;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="width:30%">
        <div class="btn-group" id="group1" data-group="1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="outline-color:red; " onclick="switch_to_green(this)">Sunday</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">Tuesday</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">Friday</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="width:70%">
        <div class="btn-group" id="group2" data-group="2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">9 am</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">2 pm</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">5 pm</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switch_to_green(this)">8 pm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do it without onclick in button? because I already have onclick in button.

Comment: @Hani Sure, I also used onclick in this example. Just call the `switch_to_green` function and pass `this` to it

Comment: I dont understand. So just put onclick in here ` <div class="btn-group" id="group2" data-group="2">`  ?

Comment: @Hani the `onclick` is in the buttons itself  not the group

Comment: You can see `onclick="switch_to_green(this)"` on each button in the two groups